# tel: href "Click to call" link not working in Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

In my Cordova android app I have a link like this

`<a href = "tel:011123456789">Click to Call</a>`

This click to call link is working in IOS as expected, but in Android the click is preventing by something like

> 11-26 11:13:00.565: D/WebCore(18944): uiOverrideUrlLoading: shouldOverrideUrlLoading() returnstrue

this is my log cat result when clicked on the phone number link and the redirection is not working.

Also i tried javascript click to override the redirection, but that also not worked.
Please help me to find a solution.

I am using Cordova 3.6

Comment: Did you tried window.location.href of that number?

Comment: Hi manukv..
I have tried ..

var href = $(this).attr("href");
     var number = href.split(":")[1];
     
     window.location.href = number;
but nothing happened

Comment: Did you gve white listing access in your config.xml?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This issues is may due to the cordova whitelist permission issue.
You can specify the access in your Config.xml file like

```
 <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

In Cordova 3.6.3 update there are some security update.

The security fixes involves creating a new whitelist for non http/s protocols. If your application uses other protocols besides http:// and https://, such as sms:, mailto:, geo:, etc., then you will need to make some configuration changes to add these protocols to the whitelist.

```
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="sms:*" launch-external="yes"/>
<access origin="market:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

add these following to your Config.xml

Just read more **[Cordova-Android Security Update](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/action_required_cordova_android_security_update?lang=en)**

Comment: Thank you ... I just put <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes"/> ... and its worked.. Thanks again